# Can I "skin" edges to be a round pipe, not rectalgular?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I had created a spring-like edges like the first image below. I applied the "Skin" modifier, but it made the line to be a rectangular pipe. Can I make it a round pipe? The modifier has only "Branch Smoothing" value and it does not seem to do anything.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. You can use two modifiers, either the bevel modifier or subdivision surface modifier. Bevel is nice if you don't want to add any loops along the axis of the screw.

Using Bevel :

[image]

Wireframe :

[image]
Using subdiv :

[image]

Wireframe :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a special reason to use the Skin modifier, you would probably be better off ..

- Activating the shipped *Add Curve: Extra Objects* add-on
- Creating an Archimedian spiral with the appropriate settings
- Using the curve's native Bevel profile in its *Geometry* panel

[image]

Yo can always convert the curve to a mesh, if you want to.

Comment: but yes, this is destructive .. :)